# Блокировки PostgreSQL в случаях SELECT FOR UPDATE

Tags: postgresql, select

Из документации postgres про явные блокировки, можно увидеть, что существуют блокировки уровня таблиц и блокировки уровня строк

Для блокировок уровня таблиц существует множество различных блокировок, вот одна из них

`ROW SHARE

Команды SELECT FOR UPDATE и SELECT FOR SHARE получают такую блокировку для своих целевых таблиц`

Для блокировок уровня строк так же существует несколько режимов, вот один из них

`FOR UPDATE В режиме FOR UPDATE строки, выданные оператором SELECT, блокируются как для изменения`

Так в чем же разница ?

В каких случаях команда SELECT FOR UPDATE будет юзать режим уровня таблицы или уровня строк и какая между ними разница

доку прочитал до конца

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не "или", а "и". Нужны и будут использованы оба механизма блокировок.

Для `SELECT FOR UPDATE` нам нужно получить блокировку на каждую интересующую нас строку в таблице - чтобы никто не мог изменить эти строки до завершения этой нашей транзакции. И чтобы подождать других, кто блокировку на эту строку взял раньше. Сам факт "кто-то взял блокировку на эту строку" хранится в самой таблице.

Но прежде этого нам нужно получить `RowShareLock` на всю таблицу, чтобы никто не мог изменить несовместимым с нашими действиями образом саму таблицу, пока мы с ней работаем. Например, попросту удалить её. А так же, чтобы мы не могли даже начать читать эту таблицу, если кто-то другой держит более строгую блокировку (например, меняет структуру таблицы).

Аналогично для прочих `select .. for ..`.

Касательно блокировки уровня таблицы, не идёт речи о том, что лишь только одна транзакция может взять такую блокировку. Если по таблице [`Conflicting Lock Modes`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html) для каждого нового запроса табличной блокировки ни с кем транзакция не конфликтует, то запрос на блокировку этого уровня будет выдан. Одновременно могут выполняться десятки и сотни конкурентных транзакций с табличной блокировкой, например, `RowExclusiveLock` уровня. Вот `AccessExclusiveLock` может быть лишь один, и никто параллельно с ним работать с таблицей не сможет, потому что этот уровень блокировки конфликтует со всеми остальными, включая самого себя.

Comment: Это исчепрывающий ответ, большое спасибо. Можете ли вы поделиться ссылками на материалы , где бы я мог подчерпуть для себя такие детали

Comment: ну, смотря "такие детали" - это какие. Я-то могу и напрямую в исходники postgresql ссылки давать, если сочту уместным. По реализации блокировок вот эти два текста в первую очередь интересны: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_15_STABLE/src/backend/storage/lmgr/README https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_15_STABLE/src/backend/access/heap/README.tuplock